# The element type Color can't be assigned to the list type Color

Tags: flutter

I have colors imported from another file named colors.dart and i don't know why can't I do this now...please help

[image]

Comment: try adding an exclamation mark after the color `rdeca!,`

Comment: add them in a list then pass to the colors list.

Answer (score 4):

As the error message indicates, you are trying to assign a variable type Color? (which is actually Color OR null) to a list of type Color.

You can either change the declaration of the list to accept nullable values or    you can make a type assertion by adding ! (only if you are sure that the value is not null.)

Like,

```
colors: [
   rdeca!,
   oranzna!
]
```

Comment: Add example from the code for clear understanding.